# error when defining function inside another function in fortran

Tags: function, compiler-errors, fortran

For some use I need to define a function inside another function inside a fortran module. 
A sample code for easy comprehension is

```
module func
implicit none
contains

real function f(x,y)
real x,y,g

real function g(r)
real r
g=r
end function g

f=x*g(y)
end function f
end module func

use func
implicit none

write(*,*) f(1.0,1.0)
end
```

This is giving lots of errors in gfortran like unexpected data declaration, expected end function f, not g....etc.

What is the correct way of defining a function inside another function in fortran?

Comment: You can make `g` an internal function of `f`.  Or, given the simplicity of your example, you could use a _statement function_.  The former is preferred and the latter is obsolescent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use an internal subprogram, see below. Note internal subprograms themselves can not contain internal subprograms.

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat contained.f90
Module func

  Implicit None

Contains

  Real Function f(x,y)

    ! Interface explicit so don't need to declare g
    Real x,y

    f=x*g(y)

  Contains

    Real Function g(r)
      Real r
      g=r
    End Function g

  End Function f

End Module func

Program testit

  Use func

  Implicit None

  Write(*,*) f(1.0,1.0)

End Program testit
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran-8 -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -O -g contained.f90 
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
   1.00000000    
ian@eris:~/work/stack$
```

Comment: Is there any such thing that an internal subprogram cannot call an external function? In my original code, when I am trying to use an external function inside the subprogram section, as you said in the answer, defined in another module, gfortran is saying undefined reference... Is there any such thing?

Comment: Need to actually see the error message and what you did.  But, from the descirption you either forgot to link a library or an object file.